# Find an expression for the power function of the test for the uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from the uniform $(\theta, \theta +1)$ distribution. To test $H_0: \theta =0$ versus $H_1: \theta >0$, use the test reject $H_0$ if $Y_n \geq 1$ or $Y_1 \geq k$, where k is a constant, $Y_1 = \min(X_1,...,X_n), Y_n = \max(X_1,...,X_n)$

Find an expression for the power function of the test.

Source of the question: Casella & Beger statistical inference exercise 8.33(b)

I know when $k < \theta$, then $Y_1 \geq k$ is always true. Thue $\beta (\theta)=1$. I don't know other three cases:

$\theta \leq k-1$

$k-1 < \theta \leq 0$

$0<\theta \leq k$

Comment: I would have thought you would also want to find $k$ which give a probability of rejecting $H_0$ of $\alpha$ when $\theta=0$.  I also wonder what you would do if you see $Y_1 < 0$, as this would be inconsistent with both $H_0$ and $H_1$, related to your $k-1 < \theta \leq 0$ case.

Comment: The interesting case is $0 < \theta \le k$.  For your $\theta \le k-1$ case, you should see $Y_1\ge k$ with probability $0$ so only need to look at $Y_n\ge 1$